Trouble splitting column with date and time Value Error: Columns must be same length as key
I'm trying to split a column that has a date and a time into two separate columns. They are objects, not datetime objects. It appears in the column as mm/dd/yyy 00:00:00 AM/PM. To try splitting I tried the str.split() method and the str.extract() method but I keep getting an error that says "Columns must be same length as key" which I assume means that not every value has a time along with a date, but I'm not sure.
extract
df_small[['Created Date', 'Time']] = df['Created Date'].str.extract('(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', expand=True)

df_small[['Created Date', 'Time']] = df['Created Date'.str.split(' ', expand=True)

Thoughts?

Please provide a [mre] of your input. For example can you [edit] your question to add the output of df.head().to_dict('tight')?

You only have one capturing group in your regex but try to assign it to two columns.
You should capture the date and time:
df[['Created Date', 'Time']] = df['Created Date'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)', expand=True)

Example output:
  Created Date         Time
0   09/05/2024  01:23:45 AM

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Created Date': ['09/05/2024 01:23:45 AM']})

If you want to make the time optional, use r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})(?: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M))?' as regex.
